# How to save Excel file as CSV?

Tags: c#, csv

How to save bunch of Excel file as CSV file format without asking for the save as dialog. [I don't want this dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybhrd.png).

```
wksht.SaveAs("C:\\Barcodes\\New\\"+ Date + "_" + k +".csv",Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV);
```

Comment: try xlAppClass.DisplayAlerts = true; it won't display excel alerts.

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
wbook.SaveAs("C:\\Barcodes\\New\\"+ Date + "_" + k +".csv",Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV);
```

For more details can see here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.saveas(v=office.11).aspx#Y114

Comment: What is the difference with the line the OP wrote?

Comment: i tot workbook,saveas is difference with the op wrote 1, if got mistake please correct me

Comment: The OP didn't mention that their object doesn't have a SaveAs method. Your answer is at best a guess.